# Copy of CSS not working

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010

I've got the following:

```
        .panelHeader
{
    border: 1px solid #474747;
    color: white;
background-color: #5D7B9D;
  font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
padding: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
width: 300px;
}
```

And it works great.

But now if I add a copy of it and change the name, as so:

```
        .panelHeader2
{
border: 1px solid #474747;
color: white;
background-color: #5D7B9D;
  font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
padding: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
width: 300px;
}
```

Notice I haven`t changed anything but the name, it doesn't work...

What could be the problem?

Comment: It would helpful to see the relevant markup (to which this CSS applies).

Comment: Did you change the class name in the html element as well?

Comment: Ctrl+F5 on the browser to refresh without using the cache :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both statements work fine for me when you rename the class I asume you are changing the name off the class on your element.

The code below works fine on both divs

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .panelHeader
{
    border: 1px solid #474747;
    color: white;
background-color: #5D7B9D;
  font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
padding: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
width: 300px;
}

 .panelHeader2
{
border: 1px solid #474747;
color: white;
background-color: #5D7B9D;
  font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
padding: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
width: 300px;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="panelHeader">
    hello
</div>
<div class="panelHeader2">
    hello
</div>
</body>

</html>
```